# Displaying colored variables in tkinter based on size of another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to display comic books in different colours based on the amount of stock remaining. The colour part of the function is working correctly and the object/ class is working fine but it is only displaying the text of the last object in the list as shown in the image and shell.

Function.

```
stock = StringVar()
def update_label():
    counter = 1
    for c in comics:
        stock.set("")
        counter += 1
        if c._stock >= 10:
            colour = "green"
        elif c._stock <= 3:
            colour = "red"
        elif c._stock <= 6:
            colour = "orange"
        stock.set(c._name + " - " + str(c._stock)+ " remaining")
        print (colour)
        print (stock.get())
        Label(stock_frame, textvariable=stock, fg = colour, bg ="#333333").grid(row=counter, column = 0, pady=(0,10))
```

Shell output.

```
orange
A Great Comic - 7 remaining
red
Jerry Java - 1 remaining
green
Tony Tkinter - 11 remaining
orange
Scratch The Cat - 5 remaining
red
Python Panic - 3 remaining
>>>
```

[Image of colours working but not text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uFFZ.png)
So the text and colours are working in the shell but only the colours are working in the GUI. I am assuming the problem is with the label and the text variable but I cannot figure out why it is only repeating the last object in the list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are reusing the *same* `StringVar` for *every* `Label`.  You should be allocating a `StringVar` for *each* `Label`.  You didn't provide enough code for me to test this, but I believe it would go something like:

```
stocks = [StringVar() for comic in comics]

def update_label():

    for counter, comic in enumerate(comics):
        stock = stocks[counter]
        stock.set("")

        if comic._stock >= 10:
            colour = "green"
        elif comic._stock <= 3:
            colour = "red"
        elif comic._stock <= 6:
            colour = "orange"

        stock.set(comic._name + " - " + str(comic._stock) + " remaining")
        print(colour)
        print(stock.get())
        Label(stock_frame, textvariable=stock, fg=colour, bg="#333333").grid(row=counter + 2, column=0, pady=(0, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly. I don't understand why it would matter. I thought stock.set("") would clear it each time and it would then overwrite it.

Comment: @SgtSomething, since all the labels share the same `StringVar`, when you clear it, you clear all the labels.  When you set it, you set all the labels.  That's why they all contained the last item you set.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Those few sentences are so much better than about the 15 articles I just read. Thanks again

Comment: I have had another problem. When I go to delete this now the old labels stay underneath the new ones. How would I reset the label list to nothing at the start of the function each time?

Comment: @SgtSomething, this is a new question so I suggest you write it up as a new SO question along with your latest code.  That should make it easier for someone to answer.